# Solution to overused break statements?

Tags: c#

I have a program that is completely functional, and I am now refactoring it. I am just in the process of learning c# so the original code was pretty terrible despite the fact that it ran just fine. One of the requirements of the program is that the user be able to return to the main menu at any point. I accomplished this as follows:

```
static bool bouncer = false
static void Exit(string input)
{
    if (input == "\t")
    {
        bouncer = true
    }
}
static string Prompt(string msg)
{
    // takes input and passes it to Exit() then returns the input
}
static string FunctionA()
{
    while(true)
    {
        if (bouncer == true)
        {
            break;
        }
        Prompt("whatever")
        if (bouncer == true)
        {
            break;
        }
        Prompt("whatever")
        if (bouncer == true)
        {
            break;
        }
        // return some stuff
    }
}
static void Main()
{
    bouncer = false
    // writes the menu to console and handles UI
    // FunctionA
{
```

The variable bouncer gets set to true if the user enters the "tab" character at any input point. The proliferation of break statement conditionals provides the structure that actually breaks out back to Main(). This is obviously not a very good solution and it makes the code hard to read.

Other attempts that I considered to accomplish the same task are:

1. Goto statement that jumps straight back to Main(). I scrapped this because goto has a very limited scope in c# and I don't think there is any good way to make it workable in this situation.
2. Calling Main() directly from Exit(). This is probably a bad idea, and I can't do it anyway because apparently Main() is "protected" in some way.
3. Using an event to react to TAB or ESC being pressed. It's unclear to me how I could use an event to do this since I still wouldn't be able to break right out of the event. My understanding is that the break statement has to actually be contained in the loop that needs to be broken as opposed to being written into a different function that is called from within the loop.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. I'm hoping there's something to be done with event handling or that I've overlooked something more simple. Thanks!

Comment: You might try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of it!

Comment: Is this a console program? If so why implement a menued app from the command line?  Both Winform and Webforms would make this a nit.  and it's what they were made for.

Comment: I've never used Winform before, but I'm looking at it now. Thanks for pointing me to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of coding style, the way it is works, but is seen as ugly. Unfortunately, if you need to break out immediately between sections of work, there is not a lot of ways around that.

You can change your current format of using breaks to using "`if( bContinue ) { /* do next section of work */ }`" control style. It changes the code from break out of the while loop to this:

```
static string FunctionA()
{
    bool bContinue = true;
    while( true == bContinue )
    {
        // Do initital work.
        //
        // Initial work can set bContinue to false if any error condition
        // occurs.

        if( true == bContinue ) 
        {
            // Do more work.
            int returnCheck = MakeACall(); // Presume MakeACall returns negative interger values for error, 0 or positive values for success or success with condition/extra information.
            if( 0 < returnCheck )
            {
                bContinue = false;
            }
        }

        if( true == bContinue ) 
        {
            Prompt("whatever")
            // Do more work.
            bContinue = MakeASecondCall(); // Presume that MakeASecondCall returns true for success, false for error/failure
        }

        if( true == bContinue ) 
        {
            Prompt("whatever")
            // Do more work.
            // If error encountered, set bContinue to false.
        }

        if( true == bContinue ) 
        {
            Prompt("whatever else")
            // Do more work.
            // If error encountered, set bContinue to false.
        }

        // Done with loop, so drop out.
        bContinue = false;
        // return some stuff
    }
}
```

Looking at your pseudo code, it reads like you only do a single pass through your work loop. If so, you can switch to a `Do-While(false)` format, and use the break to just drop to the bottom. Or, if you are only doing a single pass through your `FunctionA`, just do away with the `While` or `Do-While` control structure, and just use the `if(true==bContinue){ /* Do more work */ }`. It is not the cleanest of code, but when you perform long periods of serial work, you end up with such structures if you are not going to use a `while` or `do-while` for controlling the flow.

The disadvantage to using the `if(bContinue){}` style is that when an error condition occurs during the early stages of the process, the code does not exit out as quickly from the function as a `break` out of the `while()` or `do-while()` structure if the error occurs near the top of the work, as there will be the series of `if` statements that the code will test and then skip over. But it is readable, and if you use a descriptive name for your control variable (ie, `nContinue` or `bContinue` or `workLoopControl`) it should be fairly obvious that it is the master control flag for the function's work flow to whoever works or reviews the code after you.

Comment: I'll implement this style. It really doesn't function any differently than my original code, but reorganizing it in this way at least improves readability :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an infinite loop and break statements, try using a conditional flag instead.

```
static void FunctionA()
{
  bool done = false;
  string response = string.Empty;
  while (!done)
  {
    response = Prompt("whatever");
    if(response == '\t')
    {
      done = true;
    }
  }
}
```

As a side note, I'm not sure why you have 'string' as the return type of several methods (e.g., 'FunctionA') when you aren't using the return value.  That's why the code I gave above has it as 'void'.

Comment: It appears that OP just commented out the section of code that `// returns some stuff`

Comment: FunctionA and the others return stuff in the actual program. I just didn't think to write them in as void for the dummy code. That solution makes a lot of sense, though I was under the impression that the conditional on the while loop would only be evaluated with each iteration of the loop. Is that incorrect?

Comment: That is correct. If you need to break out of the MIDDLE of a while loop, you have to use a break, as you show in your posted code example in the question.

Comment: @StarPilot That's the problem. It seems like a poor approach to use a load of breaks. Do you have any suggestions as to how this could be restructured to avoid using the ridiculous number of breaks?

Comment: This solution works for the given code sample.  Perhaps you could edit your question with more details to explain why you need multiple breaks inside the loop, and a conditional won't suffice.